# grails emacs mode - "Cannot open load file" "project-mode"

Tags: grails, emacs, elisp

I am trying to use `emacs` for grails development. Tried on [grails-emacs-mode](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-grails-mode/)

There are `emacs` and `emacs23` on my ubuntu 12.04.

```
prayag@prayag:~$ ls -l /usr/share/emacs[tab][tab]
emacs/   emacs23/
```

As the grails-emacs-mode suggests, I copied `grails-mode.el` and `primary.org` files to my `emacs23/site-list`

```
prayag@prayag:~$ ls -l /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3013 Nov 17 00:39 debian-startup.elc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 17 00:39 dictionaries-common
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18205 Feb 14 01:11 grails-mode.el
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Feb 14 01:11 primary.org
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106 Sep 22 01:16 subdirs.el
```

Then, created `init.el` inside `.emacs.d` as there exists no `.emacs` file in home directory. The `init.el` conatains

```
(require 'grails-mode)
(setq grails-mode t)
(setq project-mode t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.gsp$" . nxml-mode)) ; Use whatever mode you want for views.
(project-load-all) ; Loads all saved projects. Recommended, but not required.
```

now, opening `emacs23` doesn't show any grails in the menubar.

I also tried

```
M-x
load-file .emacs.d/init.el
```

which throws

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/prayag/.emacs.d/init.el':

File error: Cannot open load file, project-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

[image: grails-emacs]

On starting `emacs23 --debug-init`, following error is thrown.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "project-mode")
  require(project-mode)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/grails-mode.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 422
  load-with-code-conversion("/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/grails-mode.el" "/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/grails-mode.el" nil t)
  require(grails-mode)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/prayag/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 23
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/prayag/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/prayag/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/prayag/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[grails-mode](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-grails-mode/) requires project-mode as mentioned on the emacs-grails-mode page. So, you'll also need to install [project-mode](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-project-mode/).

Also grab the remaining groovy packages(all but grails-mode) from [here](https://github.com/russel/Emacs-Groovy-Mode).

[emacs-grails-mode-ext](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/emacs-grails-mode-ext) is a modest contribution to grails-mode allowing you to run Grails commands directly from emacs. For a given project(project-mode), you can run Grails commands such as *create-domain-class*, *create-service*, etc.

I also use the function *ido-find-file-in-tag-files* from [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/TextMate), I bind it to *C-x C-M-f*  .

Simple guide with emacs-grails-mode:

- Create a project from the command line or *eshell* -> *grails create-app yourapp*
- Using *dired*, go to your Grails project folder
- *M-x project-new* -> to create a new project(project-mode)
- *M-x project-save* -> Save the project
- *M-x project-load-and-select* -> Your project-name as argument
- There's also a Grails menu if you use the menubar

You could also use [my current emacs setup here](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/emacs-rimero-setup), if you have emacs24 installed. I believe that it's available for Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm not sure. I usually build emacs from source on OSX or I use [emacs-snapshot](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) in Ubuntu.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Liked The Geek's Way. https://github.com/rimerosolutions/emacs-rimero-setup looks awesome. I will try it. \,,/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Grail-mode at all. I've just clicked your link, and they state that project-mode is a dependency:

> Dependencies:
>   project-mode is the only dependency.

As a consequence you will also have to install it. [Link to the Emacs project code](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-project-mode/).
I am hoping for you this project does not have additional dependencies...

As a side note: **later**, try to install the last emacs (v24) which embeds a very convenient way to deal with package installation and dealing with packages dependencies. I've just check it out, it is present on an alternative (but very know) repository: Marmalade-repo.org.

Comment: Yes, dependencies project-mode.el and levenshtein.el weren't added. Adding them to emacs23/site-list and adding (require 'project-mode)
(project-load-all) ; to init.el worked. \,,/